# Druid coordinator cannot talk to the rest of the cluster

Tags: linux, linux-kvm, cluster, hadoop

I'm deploying a 5-KVM cluster with Hadoop, Spark and Apache Druid for testing purposes, and I'm stuck on an issue about Druid. The running cluster is organized as this:

- `hadoop-master`: also hosts Druid master node (**coordinator-overlord**);
- `hadoop-worker1`: also hosts Druid first data node (**middleManager** and **historical**);
- `hadoop-worker2`: also hosts Druid second data node;
- `spark-worker1`: also hosts Druid query node (**broker** and **router**).

I've also configured a Zookeeper cluster distributed on all those machines plus the `spark-worker2`. It is functioning correctly as commands like `echo conf | nc localhost 2181` informs all the hosts as participants (the leader is currently node 3). I've put on all the `common.runtime.properties` this line:

```
druid.zk.service.host=hadoop-master,hadoop-worker1,hadoop-worker2,spark-worker1,spark-worker2
druid.zk.paths.base=/var/lib/zookeeper
```

All the nodes of Druid starts up without errors, but on `hadoop-master` the coordinator continuously logs these lines:

```
2023-06-21T22:46:50,012 INFO [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.duty.LogUsedSegments - Found [0] used segments.
2023-06-21T22:46:50,012 INFO [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.DruidCoordinator - Using round-robin segment assignment.
2023-06-21T22:46:50,012 WARN [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.duty.RunRules - Uh... I have no servers. Not assigning anything...
2023-06-21T22:46:50,012 INFO [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.duty.MarkAsUnusedOvershadowedSegments - Skipping MarkAsUnused as there are no overshadowed segments.
2023-06-21T22:46:50,012 INFO [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.duty.EmitClusterStatsAndMetrics - Load Queues:
2023-06-21T22:46:53,445 INFO [org.apache.druid.metadata.SqlSegmentsMetadataManager-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.metadata.SqlSegmentsMetadataManager - No segments found in the database!
```

In fact, Druid console does not show the coordinator:

[Image: services on Druid console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekL32.png)

I'm stuck. What should I supposed to do?

Comment: Actually, router is emitting an exception, _org.apache.druid.java.util.common.IOE: No known server_.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized that I need to add metadata database configuration on all nodes of my cluster (on `conf/druid/cluster/_common/common_runtime.properties`). In my case, I'm using MySQL as metadata store.